# tensorflow transfer learning: how to do batch size instead of one by one

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, transfer-learning

In tensorflow transfer learning [retrain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) example, they get the bottleneck value of each image one by one:

```
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()
...
bottleneck_values = run_bottleneck_on_image(sess, image_data, 
jpeg_data_tensor, decoded_image_tensor,resized_input_tensor, 
bottleneck_tensor)
```

In run_bottleneck_on_image, for each image_data, they do:

```
# First decode the JPEG image, resize it, and rescale the pixel values.
resized_input_values = sess.run(decoded_image_tensor,
                              {image_data_tensor: image_data})
# Then run it through the recognition network.
bottleneck_values = sess.run(bottleneck_tensor,
                           {resized_input_tensor: resized_input_values})
bottleneck_values = np.squeeze(bottleneck_values)
return bottleneck_values
```

Is there a way to get the bottleneck values for a BATCH size of images at one time, instead of running it one by one which is much slower and inefficient with a GPU?